# Can i catch return false from server in windows.location?

Tags: javascript

If I write  `windows.location="/start/open";`  and from server side return `false`  I get blank page.  
Can I catch this?

Comment: What do you mean by returning `false` from server side? With which format / Content-Type?

Comment: i was wrong, my server(Node) return `res.status(400).send("Not found")`

Answer (score 1):

No

> windows.location=*some URL* is just like normal request

but you can use the HTTP **referer** (not misspelled) and redirect client back to the page it was earlier on

eg. in PHP

```
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

in ASP.NET

```
Response.Redirect("Location: " +Request.ServerVariables.Get("HTTP_REFERER"));
```

Java Servlet

```
response.setHeader("Location: "+ request.getHeader("HTTP_REFERER"));
```

Comment: yes. I can use ajax for catch response, but i don't want rewrite all code. i  thought what can catch with simple js..

Comment: ok. I decided to return the page where the request was made.  in Expressjs ` res.redirect(req.headers.referer);`

Comment: Cool, but beware of one caveat though you may probably be knowing but still , if user types in the URL directly in browser (ie. didn't use links/server redirect to go there) the referer field would be blank so make some default redirect for that case too.